# cant search through records when using timestamps , using typeorm

Tags: timestamp, nestjs, typeorm

Using Nestjs + typeorm / after adding timestamps to User entity, I can no longer find and search through related tables using this:

```
  async getSavedForums(user: User) {
    const savedForums = await this.saveForumRepo.find({
      where: {
        owner: user,
      },
      relations: {
        forum: true,
      },
    });
```

, and I have to change it to this:

```
  async getSavedForums(user: User) {
    const savedForums = await this.saveForumRepo.find({
      where: {
        owner: {
          id: user.id,
        },
      },
      relations: {
        forum: true,
      },
    });
```

to check only records Id.
(I know the cause of this problem)
my only question is: Is there any way to ignore timestamps in similar situations? or is there any cleaner code to reach same result?

I tried to use only records id to search and find through records , but im loooking for a cleaner code to reach it.

Users model:

```
@Entity({ name: 'users' })
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  email: string;

  @Column({ default: '' })
  username: string;

  @Column({ default: '' })
  name: string;

  @Column({ default: '' })
  phoneNumber: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  bio: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  image: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  coverImage: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  dateOfBirth: Date;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  gender: string;

  @Column()
  password: string;

  @Column({ default: false })
  isEmailVerified: boolean;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  created_at: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updated_at: Date;

  @OneToMany(() => Tokens, (token) => token.id)
  token: Tokens[];

  @OneToMany(() => Forum, (forum) => forum.id)
  forum: Forum[];

  @OneToMany(() => Comment, (comment) => comment.id)
  comment: Comment[];

  @OneToMany(() => Savedforum, (savedforum) => savedforum.id)
  savedforum: Savedforum[];

  @OneToMany(() => Report, (report) => report.id)
  report: Report[];
}
```

Comment: Can you share the codes of your model definitions and relations?

Comment: @MohsenMahoski i did